# MaterialUI: Why does setting background color on Select component hides the InputLabel text and how could I avoid it happening?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, inline-styles, css-in-js

Basically I'm just trying to change the background color on dropdown elements but I also would like to keep the default text showing there. Right now, if I don't set up background color explicitly on the `Select` component, text specified in `InputLabel` shows up just fine, but as soon as I add `style={{backgroundColor: "rgb(232, 241, 250)"}}` to the `Select`, this `InputLabel` text disappears. Why does it happen and what could be done to fix this?

Code Snippet:

```
<FormControl required fullWidth={true} size="small">
  <InputLabel htmlFor="name" style={{color: "#000"}}>Тема обращения</InputLabel>
  <Select
     variant="filled" 
     style={{backgroundColor: "rgb(232, 241, 250)"}}
     value={props.selectedTheme?.id || ''}
     onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
     {props.themes.map(t => (<MenuItem key={t.id} value={t.id}>{t.name}</MenuItem>))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot with the issue]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be specifying the `variant` on the `FormControl` element instead of on the `Select` element. With putting it on the `Select`, the `InputLabel` element is not getting the appropriate styling for the "filled" variant.

Here's the beginning of the ["filled" style for InputLabel](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/InputLabel/InputLabel.js#L56):

```
  /* Styles applied to the root element if `variant="filled"`. */
  filled: {
    // Chrome's autofill feature gives the input field a yellow background.
    // Since the input field is behind the label in the HTML tree,
    // the input field is drawn last and hides the label with an opaque background color.
    // zIndex: 1 will raise the label above opaque background-colors of input.
    zIndex: 1,
```

Note the comment indicating that the z-index is needed to raise the label above opaque background colors (as you are setting on the Select).

Here's a working example demonstrating the `variant` on the `FormControl`:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl
        variant="filled"
        size="small"
        className={classes.formControl}
      >
        <InputLabel
          style={{ color: "#000" }}
          id="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
        >
          Age
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          style={{ backgroundColor: "rgb(232, 241, 250)" }}
          labelId="demo-simple-select-filled-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-filled"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Filled Select with background color]